# Excel 2016 Chart Data Labels Always Empty

Tags: excel, charts

I have several bar charts, all configured to show Data Labels.
The data labels object box is showing (I can also apply Fill and Border colors to it). However, this object is always EMPTY. Regardless of what I tick to show (e.g. Values, Values from Cells, Series Name, etc...) - it is always empty, with the minimum (shrunk) width (as it should expand per the value presented). If I tick to show the "Legend Key" - a colored square does show to the left of the empty label box.

There's no issue with the font definition, or colors, but it seems as if some underlying theme-wide setting is causing this behavior with all charts on this Workbook.

I have a matching Workbook before some formatting (branding) were applied, in which Data Labels are working just fine. I compared all Data Labels settings and options - they are identical.

Any idea where else can I look?

Thanks!

Comment: change the theme ?

Comment: Cannot. Branding was applied by the customer and needs to remain intact.

Answer (score 0):

Updating here that the issue is solved.
I believe it is some sort of a bug in Excel 2016.

I deleted the Data Labels and Re-created them, now it is working normally.

I have to delete per each chart where this problem was evident.